# Getting image of the player with Kinect in XNA performance issues

Tags: performance, xna, kinect

I am developing an XNA game that is using Kinect. The player seen on the screen is the real image of the person who is playing in front of Kinect sensor. For eliminating the background and getting only the player's image I am doing these operations in `kinect.AllFramesReady`:

```
using (ColorImageFrame colorVideoFrame = imageFrames.OpenColorImageFrame())
{
    if (colorVideoFrame != null)
    {
        //Getting the image of the colorVideoFrame to a Texture2D named colorVideo
    }
    //And setting its information on a Color array named colors with GetData
    colorVideo.GetData(colors); 
}

using (DepthImageFrame depthVideoFrame = imageFrames.OpenDepthImageFrame())
{
    if (depthVideoFrame != null){
        //Copying the the image to a DepthImagePixel array
        //Using only the pixels with PlayerIndex > 0 to create a Color array
        //And then setting the colors of this array from the 'colors' array by using MapDepthPointToColorPoint method, provided by Kinect SDK
        //Finally I use SetData function in order to set the colors to a Texture2D I created before
    }
}
```

But the performance is very low unsurprisingly. Because I have to use `GetData` for a color array with 640*480 = 307200 length (because of the `ColorImageFormat`) and `SetData` for another color array with 320*480 = 76800 length (because of the `DepthImageFormat`) in **every frame**!

I wonder if there is any other solutions for this problem, any alternatives for `SetData` and `GetData` maybe. Because I know that these functions moving data between the GPU and CPU and that is an expensive operation for big data. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you need to do this in every single frame? Maybe once per 5-6 frames will be enough?

Comment: In order to get the real time image of the player, I have to do this. If players raise their hands, then they want to see their hand risen in the game too. But I may give it a shot. Do you have any suggestions about how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

The Kinect for Windows Toolbox comes with a "GreenScreen-WPF" example, which should provide some insight into processing the information.  Because you are working in XNA there may be some differences, but the overall concepts should work between the two examples.

The example works by extracting multiple players.  Here is the business end of the processing function:

```
private void SensorAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    // in the middle of shutting down, so nothing to do
    if (null == this.sensor)
    {
        return;
    }

    bool depthReceived = false;
    bool colorReceived = false;

    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (null != depthFrame)
        {
            // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
            depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(this.depthPixels);

            depthReceived = true;
        }
    }

    using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        if (null != colorFrame)
        {
            // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
            colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixels);

            colorReceived = true;
        }
    }

    // do our processing outside of the using block
    // so that we return resources to the kinect as soon as possible
    if (true == depthReceived)
    {
        this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthFrameToColorFrame(
            DepthFormat,
            this.depthPixels,
            ColorFormat,
            this.colorCoordinates);

        Array.Clear(this.greenScreenPixelData, 0, this.greenScreenPixelData.Length);

        // loop over each row and column of the depth
        for (int y = 0; y < this.depthHeight; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < this.depthWidth; ++x)
            {
                // calculate index into depth array
                int depthIndex = x + (y * this.depthWidth);

                DepthImagePixel depthPixel = this.depthPixels[depthIndex];

                int player = depthPixel.PlayerIndex;

                // if we're tracking a player for the current pixel, do green screen
                if (player > 0)
                {
                    // retrieve the depth to color mapping for the current depth pixel
                    ColorImagePoint colorImagePoint = this.colorCoordinates[depthIndex];

                    // scale color coordinates to depth resolution
                    int colorInDepthX = colorImagePoint.X / this.colorToDepthDivisor;
                    int colorInDepthY = colorImagePoint.Y / this.colorToDepthDivisor;

                    // make sure the depth pixel maps to a valid point in color space
                    // check y > 0 and y < depthHeight to make sure we don't write outside of the array
                    // check x > 0 instead of >= 0 since to fill gaps we set opaque current pixel plus the one to the left
                    // because of how the sensor works it is more correct to do it this way than to set to the right
                    if (colorInDepthX > 0 && colorInDepthX < this.depthWidth && colorInDepthY >= 0 && colorInDepthY < this.depthHeight)
                    {
                        // calculate index into the green screen pixel array
                        int greenScreenIndex = colorInDepthX + (colorInDepthY * this.depthWidth);

                        // set opaque
                        this.greenScreenPixelData[greenScreenIndex] = opaquePixelValue;

                        // compensate for depth/color not corresponding exactly by setting the pixel 
                        // to the left to opaque as well
                        this.greenScreenPixelData[greenScreenIndex - 1] = opaquePixelValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // do our processing outside of the using block
    // so that we return resources to the kinect as soon as possible
    if (true == colorReceived)
    {
        // Write the pixel data into our bitmap
        this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
            new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
            this.colorPixels,
            this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
            0);

        if (this.playerOpacityMaskImage == null)
        {
            this.playerOpacityMaskImage = new WriteableBitmap(
                this.depthWidth,
                this.depthHeight,
                96,
                96,
                PixelFormats.Bgra32,
                null);

            MaskedColor.OpacityMask = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = this.playerOpacityMaskImage };
        }

        this.playerOpacityMaskImage.WritePixels(
            new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.depthWidth, this.depthHeight),
            this.greenScreenPixelData,
            this.depthWidth * ((this.playerOpacityMaskImage.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8),
            0);
    }
}
```

If you are interested in only a single player, you could look into using the player mask to more quickly extract the appropriate pixel set.  You'd fi

```
using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
{
    if (skeletonFrame != null && skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength > 0)
    {
        if (_skeletons == null || _skeletons.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength)
        {
            _skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
        }

        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(_skeletons);

        // grab the tracked skeleton and set the playerIndex for use pulling
        // the depth data out for the silhouette.
        this.playerIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < _skeletons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_skeletons[i].TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked)
            {
                this.playerIndex = i+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then step through the depth data to extract the appropriate bits:

```
depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.pixelData);

for (int i16 = 0, i32 = 0; i16 < pixelData.Length && i32 < depthFrame32.Length; i16++, i32 += 4)
{
    int player = pixelData[i16] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;
    if (player == this.playerIndex)
    {
        // the player we are tracking
    }
    else if (player > 0)
    {
        // a player, but not the one we want.
    }
    else
    {
        // background or something else we don't care about
    }
}
```

I'm pulling this code from a control I use to produce a silhouette, so it does not deal with the color stream.  However, making a call to `MapDepthFrameToColorFrame` at the appropriate time should allow you to deal with the color stream data and extract the corresponding pixels to the player's mask.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I am doing all of these operations and getting player's image very well. Only problem is that performance reduces. And I think that's because of Color Stream, because when I disable Color Stream and make Player's silhouette only black, it works nicely.